# Using pipe with str_replace causes warning about coercion

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to do an extremely simple replacement with `str_replace_all()` from `stringr`. I can get it to work in one way, but not in another. I'm just now learning the intricacies of the pipe function, and clearly don't understand it completely. Here's a reprex that shows what I mean:

```r
df <- data.frame(team=c('team_A', 'team_B', 'team_C', 'team_D'),
                 conference=c('West', 'West', 'East', 'East'),
                 points=c(88, 97, 94, 104))
#replace "West" with "Western" in the conference column
df$conference <- str_replace(df$conference, "West", "Western")

#>[1] "Western" "Western" "East"    "East"  


#try the same with pipes
df |> 
  select(conference) |> 
  str_replace("West", "Western")

#>[1] "c(\"Western\", \"West\", \"East\", \"East\")"
Warning message:
In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

I think R is telling me that the result from the `select()` statement isn't a vector, and that a vector is being coerced. That's fine, except it's not giving me the same results.

I am not sure how to specify a column to the `str_replace()` function without using the long R name (`df$conference` in this case). I'm almost certain I've seen str_replace used in a pipeline before, but the error messages are just a little too cryptic for me to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to str_replace should be a character vector and it is in the first example in the question but it is a data frame in the second example. From the str_replace help file:

> Usage:
>
> ```
> str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)
> ```
>
> ...snip...
>
> Arguments:
>
> string: Input vector. Either a character vector, or something
> coercible to one.

This works and returns a data frame (or if you are using dplyr replace transform with mutate).

```
df |> 
  transform(conference = str_replace(conference, "West", "Western"))
##     team conference points
## 1 team_A    Western     88
## 2 team_B    Western     97
## 3 team_C       East     94
## 4 team_D       East    104
```

This would also work and gives a character vector result:

```
df$conference |> str_replace("West", "Western")
## [1] "Western" "Western" "East"    "East"
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'm still not sure what is going wrong. I'm running into this error time after time: I try to apply a stringr function to a column of data, and I get this same error. For example, I wanted to count the number of words in a column using str_count, so I essentially went df |> select(column) |> str_count(...) and that's incorrect.

I suppose my question is "Tell me what the error means and how to correct it" rather than "Give me working code". Knowing the correct code, I still can't correct myself the next time the error occurs.

Comment: You passed a data frame to str_replace instead of passing a character vector.  The answer shows two versions of the correct code depending on whether you want a data frame or character vector result.